# SQL: join with an equal key and nearest key (similar to Pandas's merge as of)

Tags: sql, join, left-join, presto

For example, I have 2 tables like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

For every row in table 1, I want to get the row with

- same `customer id` and
- nearest `date` (in my case, `table2.date < table1.date`)

The result should look like this

[image]

How can I do this in SQL? I tried to search, but didn't find many things related. and what if I want to change the condition to `<=`, `>=` or `>`?

Thanks!

Note:

- please using standard SQL, as I'm not using PostgreSQL
- If I can use Python, I might simply get away with a for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Gordon - lateral join is best solution.

If lateral join is not supported, window function-based solution may come in handy.

```
with table1 (order_id, customer_id, date) as (
  select 1, 1, date '2019-10-10' union
  select 2, 1, date '2019-10-11' union
  select 3, 2, date '2019-10-11' union
  select 4, 2, date '2019-10-12' union
  select 5, 3, date '2019-10-12'
), table2 (order_id, customer_id, date) as (
  select  8, 1, date '2019-10-08' union
  select  9, 1, date '2019-10-09' union
  select 10, 1, date '2019-10-10' union
  select 11, 2, date '2019-10-10' union
  select 11, 2, date '2019-10-10' union
  select 11, 2, date '2019-10-10'
), all_rows as (
  select t1.*, t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t1.order_id order by t2.date desc) rn
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id and t2.date < t1.date
)
select * from all_rows where rn = 1
```

Comment: An additional question, is it possible to add rn=1 to the previous query? feels a bit redundant when using it seperately

Comment: To which query? `rn` is computed based on your requirements in `all_rows` CTE. It is redundant in the result since it's always 1, so if it minds, you have to explicitly list columns from `all_rows` instead of `*` (some dbs also support `select * except` construct)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `lateral join` for this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*  -- choose the columns you want
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.
      from table2 t2
      where t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id and
            t2.date < t1.date  -- do you really mean <= ?
      order by t2.date desc
      limit 1
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm using `presto`, it seems it does not support lateral join, is there any other way?

Comment: @cqcn1991 . . . When I look at the documentation it does:  https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Presto supports lateral join for long time, but recently we did some improvements in this area, so I recommend trying out Presto 322 when more complex lateral joins are in play.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen . . . Is that a performance statement?  Or would this query not work in recent (but older) versions of Presto?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's about whether a query can be decorrelated (Presto executes `LATERAL JOIN` by decorrelating into equivalent `JOIN`). TopN decorrelation was  implemented only this year. Incidentally, just as the `FETCH FIRST` syntax you used (Presto used to support non-ANSI `LIMIT` only).
If you want to stay current, join the https://prestosql.io/slack.html and watch for the release announcements. See you there!

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it's not prestodb. They're different.