# SQL grouped columns

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have selection from table (id, group, type, created). How do I select the rows only before first encounter of type 'ad' (including 'ad' row). 
In this example I need rows with ids 8207 - 8214.

```
  id   | group | type | created_at |
+------+-------+------+------------+
| 8214 |    83 | msg  | 1571726466 |
| 8213 |    83 | msg  | 1571724983 |
| 8212 |    83 | msg  | 1571724982 |
| 8211 |    83 | msg  | 1571724978 |
| 8210 |    83 | msg  | 1570861659 |
| 8209 |    83 | msg  | 1570861656 |
| 8208 |    83 | msg  | 1570861650 |
| 8207 |    83 | ad   | 1570861643 |
| 8206 |    83 | msg  | 1570861632 |
| 8205 |    83 | msg  | 1570861623 |
| 8202 |    83 | msg  | 1570861617 |
| 8203 |    83 | msg  | 1570861617 |
| 8204 |    83 | msg  | 1570861617 |
| 8200 |    83 | msg  | 1570861616 |
| 8201 |    83 | msg  | 1570861616 |
| 8197 |    83 | msg  | 1570861615 |
| 8198 |    83 | msg  | 1570861615 |
| 8199 |    83 | msg  | 1570861615 |
| 8194 |    83 | msg  | 1570861614 |
| 8195 |    83 | ad   | 1570861614 |
| 8196 |    83 | msg  | 1570861614 |
| 8192 |    83 | msg  | 1570861613 |
```

Expected:

```
+------+-------+------+------------+
| id   | group | type | created_at |
+------+-------+------+------------+
| 8214 |    83 | msg  | 1571726466 |
| 8213 |    83 | msg  | 1571724983 |
| 8212 |    83 | msg  | 1571724982 |
| 8211 |    83 | msg  | 1571724978 |
| 8210 |    83 | msg  | 1570861659 |
| 8209 |    83 | msg  | 1570861656 |
| 8208 |    83 | msg  | 1570861650 |
| 8207 |    83 | ad   | 1570861643 |
```

**UPD:** Basically I need slice of my selected rows with one row-ad on it.

Comment: Have a sub-query that returns the MIN(created_at) value where type = ad!

Comment: @jarlh. Nice thought. Just a remark since createt_at  is on descintnig order, we need MAX rather than MIN

Comment: @jarlh but it will just return one row with min created_at and no ad type. I don't see how it fits for me.

Comment: @apomene well, same here. it will just return 8214.

Comment: @apomene, oops. I feel so stupid now...

Comment: @barmaxon CTE with test data is even better than formatted text, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58492729/653539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess:

```
select *
from t
where created_at >= (select max(created_at) from t where type = 'ad')
```

However you don't specify what *only before first encounter of type 'ad'* means - is table sorted by `created_at`? Or `id`? Can duplicate `created_at` values occur?

Comment: Thx, though it doesn't solve my whole problem, but it pointed to right direction, I guess)).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Id >= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Tbl WHERE type = 'ad' GROUP BY ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where id >= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name where type = 'ad')
```

NOTE - you can change order by based on your conditions.